# Reading json content in folders and subfolders in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a folder tree,with jsons

```
Folder1
    info.json
    Subfolder1
         info.json
    Subfolder2
         info.json

Folder2
    info.json
    Subfolder1
         info.json
    Subfolder2
         info.json
```

then, i want to navigate through the folders, read the info.json, save the content (i know how to do it, with decode_json() ) and, before going to the nex folder, enter in the subfolders of the first folder (i have 3 or 4 childs in every folder, and about 10 folders)

i have think about reading fullpath of every info.json and save it in a list,(for example using locate function in linux terminal) then read every line of the list... but it is very complicated

any idea?

thanks

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have think to use locate info.json  > list.txt to save the output of the command, as i say, then open the file in php, and loop through the lines to access every info.json (opening it too and getting the content) then i have used php function json_decode to extract the info into an array... but im having troubles, because i dont know how to pass the filepath of the json

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive glob function as:
(See php doc http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#106595)

```
function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0) {
    $files = glob($pattern, $flags);

    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern) . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
        $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir . '/' . basename($pattern), $flags));
    }

    return $files;
}

$files = glob_recursive('/path/to/folder/*.json');
foreach($files as $file) { /* Do stuff */ }
```

Return an array of your file with path

Comment: that function returns first the info.json, then every json for every subfolder, in order?